# Importing Vuejs and VueI18n

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-i18n

I am integrating a platform with a browser based language switcher. I am planning to use Vuei18n for the language switcher because I am using Vue. But the thing is, there is an error showing unexpected identifier on both line 1 in my language.js and home.js. My scripts are in the same folder.

*Here is my HTML code*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Sapphire | Home</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="robots" content="all,follow">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"> <!-- BOOTSTRAP FRAMEWORKS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/spinners.css"/> <!-- PRELOADER -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/font-awesome/css/all.min.css"> <!-- FONTS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/> <!-- CUSTOM STYLES -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/static/favicon.ico"> <!-- WEB ICON -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- START OF VUE APP -->
    <div id="app">

       <!-- ================================ -->
        <!-- HEADER/NAVBAR -->
        <!-- ================================ -->
        <ife-header disable-sidebar-toggle=true :change-language='changeLanguage'></ife-header>
            <!-- ================================ -->
            <!-- PAGE CONTENT -->
            <!-- ================================ -->
              <div class="row text-center ife-home">
                <div class="p-1 col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" id="box1" >
                  <img src="assets/images/static/music.jpg" width="200px" alt="">
                  <div id="box2"><a class="clean-link" href="music.html"><i class="fas fa-4x fa-music box-icon"></i><p class="box-label text-white">{{ $t('hello') }}</p></a></div>
                </div>
              </div>

    </div>  
    <!-- END OF VUE APP -->
    <!-- ================================ -->

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery-confirm.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/popper.js/umd/popper.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/lazy/jquery.lazy.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/vue/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/components.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/vue/vue-i18n.js"></script>

    <script src="js/language.js"></script>
    <script src="js/home.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

*Here is my Vuejs code or home.js*

```
import Vue from "vue"
import { i18n } from './language.js'

var app = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    router,
    i18n,
    render: (h) => h(App)
})
```

*Here is my Vuei18n code or language.js*

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'

Vue.use(VueI18n)

export const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: 'en', //set locale
  fallbackLocale: 'en',
  messages: { en: { hello: 'Hello'}, bg: { hello: '3apeben' } } //set locale message
})
```

"I expect the output **Hello** but it displays **{{ $t('hello') }}**"

Comment: If it displays exactly **{{ $t('hello') }}**, including the curly braces, than it is not parsed by Vue for some reason. Not being in _vue_ file, somehow being escaped, not having Vue actually installed etc.

Comment: This is not an i18n issue.  Try `<p class="box-label text-white">{{'hello'}}</p>` and get that working first.

Comment: @StevenSpungin If I change it into {{'hello'}} the output is the same as **{{'hello'}}**

Comment: That shows it is not an i18n issue.  You have a configuration issue relate to parsing your template.  Start with a working project, and then slowly bring your code into it until you discover what is breaking it.

Comment: Post your App.vue file.  Is your html in a template block?

Comment: Guessing here but I'd say you're not building this app with a bundler like Webpack. If I run `import Vue from 'vue'` in my browser, I too get an _"Unexpected identifier"_ error. I highly recommend you start with a project generated by [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/)

Comment: I already did what you have said. But it doesn't change anything. I just posted my html page. Please have a look. Thank you. @StevenSpungin

Comment: You cannot mix ES6 module imports with plain old `<script src="...">` tags. Like I said last week, you need to use a bundler like Webpack. The easiest way to do so is start with a new Vue CLI project